# UIAction sheet frame

Tags: iphone

[image]I have an action sheet that I am displaying in landscape mode.

```
sheet2 = [[[UIActionSheet alloc] 

      initWithTitle:@"\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n"
      delegate:self
      cancelButtonTitle: nil destructiveButtonTitle:nil
      otherButtonTitles:NSLocalizedString(@"Merge", @"Merge button text"),NSLocalizedString(@"Refresh", @"Refresh button text"), nil] 
     autorelease];
```

How do I set the frame of it so that it looks proper in my view? See I don't want this gap between the text and the buttons.

Comment: What are you expecting it to look like? (i.e.: Define "proper".)

Comment: ok..it should cover the entire width in landscape mode but have half the heigh of landscape mode.

Comment: The "\n\n\n\n\n..." title is to make room for UILabels? Do I get that right? Why not use the Title for your message?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would be helpful if you posted the actual code snippet along with that image, because that image and that code snippet are clearly not connected. UIActionSheets by default will only take up as much space as it needs, so removing those \n's from the title should fix your problem (assuming they even exist in the code that generated that screenshot).

However, from a design perspective, you're probably just going in the wrong direction here overall. If you have to give that much explanation of the two options then you probably should just go ahead and use a new UIViewController so the user can see and read that info in properly sized text.

Or, if you give them enough information before they get to this UIActionSheet, then I would recommend making the button text more explicit. Something like "Replace Local Contacts" instead of "Refresh" and "Merge with Server Contacts" instead of just "Merge."

Comment: Hey Kenny, If only it were my application. It's part of my work and the design decisions are taken by the big wigs. My initial reaction wa s the same as yours when I saw the design document but alas I am a small organ in the scheme of things here.

Comment: I feel you. If only the non-developers would understand that the developers input on these types of decisions is valuable. Good luck!

Comment: Perhaps... you can imitate a UIActionSheet so they don't really know the difference. Perhaps create a UIView with a partial transparency and an appropriately sized UILabel and the required buttons. When they tap the Sync button, instead of displaying a UIActionSheet, just animate your custom alert-ish view so that it slides up from the bottom and they won't know the difference?